# jQuery append to a element but after text of the parent element

Tags: jquery

How can i append "span" to this html inside the a tag , but also place the parent text inside the "a" before the new "span" . I have tried all the append techniques that i know with no luck

EXAMPLE

```
<td><a>LINK</a>TEXT</td>
```

RESULT WANTED

```
<td><a>LINKTEXT<span>APPEND</span></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres just one vanilla JS way to do it... Also please next time share your attemnts so qe can fix them and not write code from strech for you.

```js
let td = document.querySelector("td");
let tdtext = document.querySelector("td").innerText;

let append = document.createElement("span");
let a = document.querySelector("a");

append.innerText = "APPEND";
a.innerText = tdtext;


td.innerHTML="";
td.appendChild(a).appendChild(append);
```

```css
span {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<td><a href="...">LINK</a>TEXT</td>
</table>
```

Result:

```
<td><a>LINKTEXT<span>APPEND</span></a></td>
```

Comment: Im not able to duplicate this and have it work - https://jsfiddle.net/r3pov12j/1/

Comment: @MShack You have to have table tag, td does not work in borwsers as it should without table tags. Also change `a` into: `let a = document.querySelector("a");` it was a overseght:   https://jsfiddle.net/6q4hz135/